# android creating .txt and .csv files throwing ENOENT No such file or directory exception

Tags: java, android, ioexception, fileoutputstream, nosuchfileexception

I've created an app and i'm just adding in the feature to export data as a .txt or .csv file but I'm getting an error on file creation. The error in logcat appears as `File write failed: java.io.IOExcepion: open failed: ENOENT (NO such file or directory)`.

 Can anyone see where i'm making a mistake?
I call the writeToFile() method passing either String txt; or String csv; into it depending on which file type is needed.
code:

```
 String txt = ".txt";
 String csv = ".csv";

 private void writeToFile(String fileType) {



        // if file name has not been entered...
        if (filename.equals("")||filename.equals(null)) {

            //display toast
            toastMsg = "Please enter a file name";
            toast();

        }

        // else if file name has been entered...
        else if (!filename.equals("")) {

            // create FileCheck
            File fileCheck = new File("/sdcard/" + filename + fileType);

            // if file exists...
            if (fileCheck.exists()) {

                // display toast
                toastMsg = "Export Error: File already exists";
                toast();


            }

            // if file does not exist...
            else if (!fileCheck.exists()) {


                try {

                    // create file
                    File myFile = new File("/sdcard/" + filename + fileType);

                    myFile.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                    OutputStreamWriter myOSW = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                    myOSW.append("file data here");
                    myOSW.close();
                    fOut.close();

                    // display toast
                    toastMsg = "file created: " + myFile.toString();
                    toast();

                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "File write failed: " + e.toString());
                    toastMsg = "file write failed: " +e.toString();
                    toast();
                }

           }    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This path doesn't exist:

```
File myFile = new File("/sdcard/" + filename + fileType);
```

Maybe you mean:

```
File myFile = new File("/mnt/sdcard/" + filename + fileType);
```

Which on some devices **may not exist** as well (sometimes these linked paths are called sdcard0, sdcard1, external_storage, ...)

You'd better use

```
File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + filename + fileType);
```

And make sure you set the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

In your manifest, which also **includes** the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission

Comment: Just tried this and still no luck, i'm getting the same error and no file creation :/

Comment: I forgot to add "/" before fileName.

Comment: added but still nothing, I just can't understand why it's not working :(

Comment: how can it say the directory does not exist when I am using .getExternalStorageDirectory() :s

Comment: Funny. If you set the WRITE permission, the file access is granted. Then, you are creating a new file in a valid path. It **has to** work. Unless you're not trying it on a **locked emulator** which doesn't give you the SD card access.

Answer (score 1):

did you give these permission in manifest file? if not give it

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

i think this will solve your problem.

Comment: I did, still no luck i'm afraid